# Ember controller, promises, and possibly rerendering template in response to user search

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember app and am a beginner. There is a form where the end user can search by specific dates for that specific item. The controller looks like (and have commented in the issue):

```
App.IpbinshowController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    searchPeriod: function(params){
      var inventory_item_id_val=this.get('id');
      var start_date_val=this.get('start_date');
      var end_date_val=this.get('end_date');

      alert('this is what I want with start_date: ' + start_date_val + ' and end_date: ' + end_date_val + ' and inventory_item_id: ' + inventory_item_id_val);

      var result = App.InventoryItem.find(inventory_item_id_val, {start_date: start_date_val, end_date: end_date_val }); // <- this works correctly

      result.then(function(){        //  This part doesn't work
        this.set('model',result);    //  <- I get 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function' for this line
      });                            //
    }
  }
});
```

How can I fix this? and make it so that template re-renders.

### Edit #1

I have the feeling that it's going to be closer to this:

```
  var result = App.InventoryItem.find(inventory_item_id_val, {start_date: start_date_val, end_date: end_date_val });
  result.then(function(){
    console.log('here are result: ');
    console.log(result);
    result.done(function(r){
      console.log('here are r: ');
      console.log(r);
      this.set('model', r);
    }.bind(this));
  });
```

because the console.log(r) is outputting correct info and I am getting an undefined on the next line - so how would I refer to this at that point? It's my first time dealing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for receiving this error is that `this` is used in different contexts and does not reference the same objects, as also pointed out by `Hrishi`.
An easy and common approach, that i usually follow is assigning this to a variable and use that instead.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pokohuku/1/edit

**js**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  testProp:"",
  actions:{
    searchPeriod: function(params){
      var self = this;
      var result= $.ajax({url:""});
      result.then(function(){
        self.set("testProp","testProp's value has been set!");
        alert(self.get("testProp"));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` is wrong. The `this` in the inner function is not the same as the `this` in the function in which it is defined. To remedy this, you can use:

```
result.then(function(){    
    this.set('model',result);
  }.bind(this));
```

Comment: thx Hrishi - hmm.... that didn't seem to do it. I don't think there's something else going on but I think you are on the right track.